# The Easiest Way To Implement SASS In WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I typically develop in CSS but I'm looking to star using SASS to become more efficient.

I've converted a CSS file from .css to .scss, which after doing so the code still functions. But after implementing variables, they don't work. The value of the variable isn't pulled through and executed.

After doing some research, it seems that WordPress doesn't allow for SASS compiling by default. How would I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: By following a guide, i guess : https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-sass-with-wordpress-a-step-by-step-guide

Answer (score 1):

You need a build step. That is, when you develop in Sass, but the browser only understands CSS, there needs to be a step, where Sass is compiled to CSS.

Wordpress won’t do that for you. One possibility is to convert the Sass file after each edit (possibly automated with a so-called watcher), then telling Wordpress to embed the resulting CSS file, not the Sass file.

Example: Assume, that you followed the [Sass install guide](https://sass-lang.com/install) and now have a command `sass`, that you can type in your terminal:

```
sass --watch input.scss style.css
```

Then the above command will create an `style.css` command every time `input.scss` is edited. You can work away on `input.scss` and `sass` will spit out updated `style.css` automatically. This will then be picked up by Wordpress (given that you’re in a theme context, e.g., `wp-content/themes/my-sass-theme`).